# shell script in a here-document used as input to ssh gives no result

Tags: shell, awk, ssh, grep, eof

I am piping a result of grep to AWK and using the result as a pattern for another grep inside EOF (not sure whats the terminology there), but the AWK gives me blank results. Below is part of the bash script that gave me issues.

```
ssh "$USER"@logs << EOF
  zgrep $wgr $loc$env/app*$date* | awk -F":" '{print $5 "::" $7}' | awk -F"," '{print $1}' | sort | uniq | while read -r rid ; do
  zgrep $rid $loc$env/app*$date*;
done
EOF
```

I am really drawing a blank here beacuse of no error and Im out of ideas.

Samples:

I am greping log files that looks like below:

```
app-server.log.2020010416.gz:2020-01-04 16:00:00,441 INFO [redacted] (redacted) [rid:12345::12345-12345-12345-12345-12345,...
```

I am interested in rid and I can grep that in logs again:

```
zgrep $rid $loc$env/app*$date*
```

`loc`, `env` and `date` are working properly, but they are outside of EOF.

The script as a whole connects to ssh and goes out properly but I am getting no result.

Comment: Without seeing samples of input and expected output it is very difficult to get requirement completely, so please do add samples in your post and let us know then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 more info added, please let me know if need more.

Comment: IMHO, what we could do to solve these kind of problems is: 1st step- Prepare the command to run on target server(from where actual logs belongs to) and once it is done 2nd step- Use that with changes per ssh needed into it to run it from ssh. Now let us come on 1st step- to first prepare command on target server itself, for that we need to know what sample output you need so please be more clear in it.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 the original command is working as expected on ssh server ```zgrep $wgr $loc$env/app*$date* | awk -F":" '{print $5 "::" $7}' | awk -F"," '{print $1}' | sort | uniq | while read -r rid ; do zgrep $rid $loc$env/app*$date*;```. Of course think like ```wgr``` and ```loc``` are changed to propper values. But what are kind of changed that are need for ssh server?

Comment: I think you need to escape $5 and $7

Comment: You should tag this with `ssh` plus whatever shell you're using as it's a shell/ssh question, not an awk or grep question in as much as you could have the same problem with perl or several other tools that require quoting and escaping appropriate to your shell/ssh command. Also `EOF` in your code is a string you made up to start/end your here-document, it could be any string such as `FOOBAR` or `!`, it's not related to the tag `eof` so you should remove that tag.

Comment: To debug your problem - start with a much simpler command (e.g. start with `awk '{print $0}' file` and then move on to `awk '{print "foo:", $0}' file`) inside your here-document and figure out how to do THAT before moving onto a long multi-command pipeline with a shell read loop at the end!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immediate problem is that the dollar signs are evaluated by the local shell because you don't (and presumably cannot) quote the here document (because then `$wqr` and `$loc` etc will also not be expanded by the shell).

The quick fix is to backslash the dollar signs, but in addition, I see several opportunities to get rid of inelegant or wasteful constructs.

```sh
ssh "$USER"@logs << EOF
  zgrep "$wgr" "$loc$env/app"*"$date"* |
  awk -F":" '{v = \$5 "::" \$7; split(v, f, /,/); print f[1]}' |
  sort -u | xargs -I {} zgrep {} "$loc$env"/app*"$date"*
EOF
```

If you want to add decorations around the final `zgrep`, probably revert to the `while` loop you had; but of course, you need to escape the dollar sign in that, too:

```sh
ssh "$USER"@logs << EOF
  zgrep "$wgr" "$loc$env/app"*"$date"* |
  awk -F":" '{v = \$5 "::" \$7; split(v, f, /,/); print f[1]}' |
  sort -u |
  while read -r rid; do
    echo Dancing hampsters "\$rid" more dancing hampsters    
    zgrep "\$rid" "$loc$env"/app*"$date"*
  done
EOF
```

Again, any unescaped dollar sign is evaluated by your *local* shell even before the `ssh` command starts executing.

Comment: getting the following error when trying to run it: ```awk: cmd. line:1: {v = $5 "::" $7; split(v, f, /,/) print f[1]}awk: cmd. line:1: {v = $5 "::" $7; split(v, f, /,/) print f[1]}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                   ^ syntax error

awk: cmd. line:1:                                   ^ syntax error
```

Comment: Sorry about that, no way to test this really without setting up a clone of your setup; but I added the missing semicolon. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but I have a question if it would be possible to echo current rid I am greping? Something like ```echo -e '\033[1mCurrently greping $rid:\033[0m'```?  And I'm sorry if I sounded condescending, I really appreciate the time you spent on helping me out.

Comment: Try `tee /dev/stderr |` after the `sort`; but this is not portable. `xargs -t` gives less useful output, and isn't entirely portable either IIRC.

Comment: ```tee /dev/stderr``` only prints parameters for grep before the greps starts. Is there a way to print it before every grep if there are multiple rids?

Comment: That's actually what it does, though ordering could be erratic in practice because of buffering. I'm thinking it's a feature, but you could obviously pass something more complex to `xargs`, like `xargs sh -c 'for rid; do echo coloring noise "\$rid"; zgrep "\$rid" "$loc$env"/app*"$date"*; done' _` (pretty brittle quoting there; hope I got it at least approximately right).

Comment: ... Though maybe then simply revert to the `while read -r` loop you had, with the same decorations, but of course without the quoting errors inside the loop.

Comment: When I try to go back to ```while read -r line``` and when I do ```echo $line``` it's empty as if it does not save the result of original grep.

Comment: Because you need to backslash that dollar sign too. See update just now.

Comment: Your final edit worked, I can't thank you enough for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: If the sort order is not important, you could further optimize by refactoring the `uniq` into the Awk script.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following. Fair warning I couldn't test it since lack of samples. By doing this approach we need not to escape things while doing ssh.

```
##Configure/define your shell variables(wgr, loc, env, date, rid) here.
printf -v var_wgr %q "$wgr"
printf -v var_loc %q "$loc"
printf -v var_env %q "$env"
printf -v var_date %q "$date"

ssh -T -p your_pass user@"$host" "bash -s $var_str" <<'EOF'

# retrieve it off the shell command line
zgrep "$var_wgr $var_loc$var_env/app*$var_date*" | awk -F":" '{print $5 "::" $7}' | awk -F"," '{print $1}' | sort | uniq | while read -r rid ; do
zgrep "$rid $var_loc$var_env/app*$date*";
done
EOF
```